# Apache denying requests with VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

This is the error I get in my log:

> Permission denied: /home/ross/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

My VirtualHost is pretty simple:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
 ServerName jotter.localhost
 DocumentRoot /home/ross/www/jotter/public
 DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

 <Directory /home/ross/www/jotter/public>
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>

 CustomLog /home/ross/www/jotter/logs/access.log combined
 ErrorLog /home/ross/www/jotter/logs/error.log
 LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I can't see why Apache is looking for a `.htaccess` there and don't know why this should stop the request. Thanks.

Comment: Fancy letting me know why it should be closed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the way around this is to set permissions correctly on the following directories:

- **site directory**: `chmod 755 /home/ross/www/jotter`
- **/home**: `chmod 711 /home/your_username`

From bobpeers.com ([Google cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:eWuOF-ecs4QJ:bobpeers.com/linux/apache_virtual_hosts.php+setting+up+a+development+virtual+host&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)).

Comment: It's not called a workaround when it's the proper configuration. :)

Answer (score 0):

When serving a page, Apache will check for an `.htaccess` file in each directory component starting at the root:

```
- /.htaccess
- /home/.htaccess
- /home/ross/.htaccess
```

Apache was unable to open your `/home/ross/.htaccess` file, either because it didn't have execute permission to `/home/ross` or read permission on `/home/ross/.htaccess`.

In order to serve pages, you'll need to add execute permissions for Apache to each directory component along the way. Read permission gives Apache the ability to generate indexes for a directory if you choose to do so; read permission is not necessary to open a file if you know its name.